# Compare 2 column from 2 file and print base on condition

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have two files, `fileA` (error code list and threshold value) and `fileB` (error log) as below:

`FileA`:

```
(ERRCODE-000004) 100
(ERRCODE-000090) 50
(ERRCODE-000110) 100
(ERRCODE-000092) 50  
(ERRCODE-000419) 100
```

`FileB`:

```
user@hostname 3 (ERRCODE-000003) This is error description
user@hostname 14 (ERRCODE-000090) This is error description
user@hostname 871 (ERRCODE-000090) This is error description
```

I want to print lines in `FileB` that contain an error code from column one from `FileA` *and* have an error count greater than the treshold value in `fileA`.

```
(column three in fileB = column one in fileA) AND
(column two in fileB > column two in fileA )
```

Expected result:

```
user@hostname 871 (ERRCODE-000090) This is error description
```

I have tried

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$3] && $2>=50' fileA fileB
```

but this has the second condition hardcoded (`$2>=50`).

Comment: i try below command : 
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$3] && $2>=50' fileA fileB 
but... for condition (column twoo in fileB > column twoo in fileA ) stil manual input ($2>=50) like above command. Any idea how can i get value of column twoo in fileA instead of manual input?

Comment: I have edited your question and added your comment to it. You were very close to the solution, but not showing what you've tried so far is bad for the question as people assume you just want them to do your work for you - always add your efforts from the start for future questions.

Comment: Sorry, my bad and thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the presence of a key in the array with the `in` keyword:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $3 in a && $2>a[$3]' filea fileb
```

Note that this assumes that filea has a single entry per code